# Google Apps Script - Send non repetitive email when condition met

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

```
function Buy() {
  // Fetch the values from column A
 var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Buy").getRange("A2:A7").getValues();

  if (values <= -5){
    // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email").getRange("E2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'Buy Goods ' + values; // Second column
    var subject = 'Buys';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  } 

}
```

Example Google Sheet Data in Column A - A2:A7

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zg12.png)

I am running above script but can't get the email where i am going wrong

Expected outcome in Email:

Buy Goods

Apples
Berries

```
function Buy() {
  // Fetch the values from column A
 var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Buy").getRange("A2:A7").getValues();

  if (values <= -5){
    // Fetch the email address
    var emailRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Email").getRange("E2");
    var emailAddress = emailRange.getValue();
    // Send Alert Email.
    var message = 'Buy Goods ' + values; // Second column
    var subject = 'Buys';
    MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
  } 

}
```

I a expected this to return values and send email

Comment: What's the moment in which the mail should be sent?, When at least one value is less than -5?, The mail should include only the products which need to be bought?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function Buy() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const bsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const esh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  const values = bsh.getRange("A2:B7").getValues();
  const email = esh.getRange("E2").getValue();
  values.forEach((v, i) => {
    if (v[0] <= -5) {
      var message = 'Buy Goods ' + v[1]; // Second column
      var subject = 'Buys';
      MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, message);
    }
  })
}
```